# Highlight current page in navbar using PHP includes?

Tags: php, highlight, navbar

I have an index.php page which includes a navBar.inc page to render the top nav bar. I also have an external stylesheet. My goal is to highlight the current page in that navbar via PHP.

I've tried to implement it, but it isn't working as I expected.

I placed PHP code at the top of the index.php page: `<?php $thisPage="About"; ?>`

Then in each `li` in the navBar.inc file, I have code that is supposed to change the id of each `li`, for example: `<li><?php if ($thisPage=="About") echo " id=\"currentPage\""; ?>><a href="index.php">ABOUT</a></li>`

And of course, in my external CSS I have: `#currentPage {color:black;}`

But when I upload the files to the server and try it out, it actually writes id="currentPage" to the page rather than assigning it that id. Also, there are >'s between each menu item. See image link below.

[Image](http://cl.ly/image/0g011Y0A2s3m)

Can you help me get this working? I'm almost there I think! Thanks!

Note: This is my very first exposure to PHP. Syntax is a bit confusing, but looks interesting!

Comment: Are you against using javascript/jQuery? You could accomplish this with a few simple lines of jQuery for instance.

Comment: Actually, I'd MUCH prefer using either of those. But from my search results, it appeared easier to include that navbar on all pages using PHP, so I figured if I'm using PHP already, I might as well use PHP to do the highlighting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently closing the `<li>` tag prior to echoing the variable, which means it's rendering the `id` attribute and the `>` to screen:

```
<li><?php if ($thisPage=="About") echo " id=\"currentPage\""; ?>>
   ^                                                            ^
<a href="index.php">ABOUT</a></li>
```

You need to place your id attribute inside the `<li>` element like this:

```
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="About") echo " id=\"currentPage\""; ?>>
<a href="index.php">ABOUT</a></li>
```

As mentioned, you could accomplish this using javascript/jQuery, but this will work.

**EDIT:**

Try:

```
#currentPage a { color: black !important; }
```

Which overrides the prior styles you've set in your .CSS file.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that only took away the id=currentPage text. The >'s are still there, and the CSS which changes the text to black isn't taking effect either.

Comment: That's odd. If you post more of your code as part of the question, it would be easier to see where the problem might be.

Comment: My last comment was incorrect. All is well except the CSS to change the text to black isn't working. But the CSS is very simple - must be a problem with assigning the ID? Note: I've tried #currentPage and also #currentPage a, neither work.

Comment: I've tried #currentPage a {color:black;} and also #currentPage {color:black;}. A few lines above I set the default in this way: #navBar ul li a {color:gray;} Neither are working.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help! Trying it as a class didn't work either. :/

Comment: Ok, back to your original and try this with your css: `#currentPage a { color: black !important; }` - we'll get there.

Comment: Thank you! !important did the trick. :) I'm not sure why, but it works. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome. `!important` overrides prior "cascading" rules that you set in your stylesheet. Basically, it overrides the `#navBar ul li a {color:gray;}` you set earlier. Don't forget to accept the answer! :)